# Vector in a function - Crash

Tags: c++

can anybody tell me what is wrong with this C++ code?

```
int countit(int n) {
vector<int>divisors;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) divisors.push_back(i);
    }
return divisors.size();
}
```

I get no compile errors, but when i run the .exe i get a standard windows "x has stopped working" popup.
I am guessing this has something to do with appending the divisors to the vector defined inside the function, but i have no idea why is this illegal. I am a bit of a rookie.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Zero division! In the first iteration `i = 0` so `n % i` crashed!

Comment: Oh dear, I must look like a total idiot right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unhandled arithmetics/division by zero exception.

Comment: Nah, you don't look like an idiot right now, I've never understood why some processors act up on such a trifle as a zero division. The PowerPC didn't do it, and I was always glad it didn't. Pitty that we're stuck with the X86-Architecture now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call "n % i", it divides n by i. So when i is 0, it will crash. Because dividing by 0 is illegal.

Fix:

```
int countit(int n) {
    vector<int> divisors;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return (divisors.size());
}
```

Comment: Or you could start the loop at `i = 1` instead of adding a comparison to every iteration.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I didn't think about that, as I am used to loops doing a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

In your `n % i`, `i` is starting from 0 => division by 0 => crash.